# Calculating Area of a Circle In C

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the area of a circle in C as an assignment, I've written some code to help me do this, but it's not giving the expected results, It is supposed to give the following results in order for it to get approved:

**This is what the result should be:**

> Input Result
> 5.0 Please enter the radius: The area of the circle is 78.539750

**This is the result I am getting:**

> Please enter the radius: The area of the circle is 78.537498

Has anyone got any ideas? They would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void)
{
  double PI = 3.14159;

  /* declare the other required variables */
  float area, radius;


  
  /* get the input from the console */
  printf("Please enter the radius:\n");
  scanf("%f",&radius);
 

  /* compute the area */
  area = PI * radius * radius;


  /* write out the answer */
  printf("The area of the circle is %f\n", area);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to use `double` instead of `float`. Remember to change the `scanf` format for that though.

Comment: Your PI is not very precise, maybe use `M_PI` from `math.h`.

Comment: @Cheatah Note that there's no `M_PI` specified in standard C. It's added by e.g. POSIX though, and exists in the MSVC `math.h` header as well.

Comment: A `#define PI 3.14159265358979323846` or `#define PI 4. * atan(1)` (value is the same, the first avoids a header dependency and eliminates the computation -- but a good compiler should make that optimization for you)